# Where is the hidden storage?

Tags: c++

I am little confused over the following situation

```
const char c = 'C';
char * p = const_cast<char *>(&c);

*p = 'K';
cout << " c = " << c << endl;
cout << " *p = " << *p << endl;

printf("c's address      : %u\n", &c);
printf("P is pointing to : %u\n", p);
```

Which outputs as below on execution

```
c = C
*p = K
c's address      : 3221180271
P is pointing to : 3221180271
```

Here I can observe that both '&c' and 'p' having the same address in the memory.

Then what is the hidden mechanism by which 'p' is capable of storing a different value than 'c' is storing whereas both share the same address space in the memory?

Answer (score 11):

There is no "hidden storage". These lines

```
const char c = 'C'; 
char * p = const_cast<char *>(&c); // NO!
```

seriously violate [`const`-correctness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness). You're creating a non-`const` pointer to something that is originally `const`. **Do not do that ever.** While the cast itself is fine, if you attempt to dereference `p` it'll invoke *undefined behavior*, meaning *anything can happen*, including the behavior you've just described.

That being said, what's going on is that the compiler is [folding the constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) `c` so that the first `cout` statement prints out `C`. So the compiler probably turned the `cout` statements into these:

```
cout << " c = " << 'C' << endl; // Note literal 'C' instead of variable c
cout << " *p = " << *p << endl;
```

So while the second `cout` statement reflects the new value of `c` by dereferencing `p`, the first `cout` statement isn't affected.

The first `cout` wasn't affected because the compiler assumed that the value of `c` will never change (it is `const` after all). With that assumption the compiler replaced the variable access with the constant value itself.

You've violated the compiler's assumption when you did this:

```
*p = 'K'; // NO!
```

since `p` points to the constant `c` and you've just changed it to `K`, giving you the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: Thanks for the reminder. I've made it a bit clearer about where exactly the UB is happening. :-)

Comment: +1 for pointing out substitution of constant variable for literal value at compile-time.

Answer (score 5):

```
const char c = 'C';
char * p = const_cast<char *>(&c);

*p = 'K';
```

This is undefined behaviour. If an object is originally `const` you cannot write to it, even after `const_cast`. It doesn't help much to reason about what and how the code does something when you are in the realm of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Others have explained that this is undefined behaviour. What's probably happening behind the scenes is that the compiler spots that `c` is const, so allows its value to be cached in a register. When you later read the value of `c` to print it out, the compiler doesn't bother fetching it from memory (it's `const`, so it can't have changed, right?), but just uses the cached value instead.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined behaviour. The compiler is allowed to optimize (e.g. keep in a register) things that it knows are immutable.

There is a slight chance that marking the char `volatile` would make the compiler respond more in expected fashion. Keep in mind that it is still  undefined behaviour nonetheless